# Setting up AWS Loadbalancer Healthcheck for Mediawiki site

Tags: amazon-ec2, mediawiki

We have an AWS Instance running MediaWiki. Now we want to put it behind a ELB Load Balancer.

The ELB needs an address on the MediaWiki server to ping, so it receives a 200 response.

I have tried "/" as the address but that looks like its timing out.

What is the correct / good address on a mediawiki site to ping for a health check?

Comment: Why does the connection time out? That's probably the problem you should investigate. MediaWiki should redirect the request to `/` to the wikis main page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Application load balancers you can specify values or ranges of values between 200 and 499 for the response code in the health check definition.So if the Mediawiki is responding with a redirect you could accept a 301/302 as a valid health check as well.

If you want a specific path (or using Classic Load balancer) your ELB expects a  200 (HTTP OK) response code and you will need to identify the path .In order to find out the exact path ,try to curl the Mediawiki server directly from within the VPC.For example ,the below mentioned curl results in a redirect(301) to a new location http://www.google.com/

```
$ curl -Iv google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.167.110...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.167.110) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.google.com/
Location: http://www.google.com/
```

Trying the curl to the new location results in a 200 OK response.

```
$ curl -Iv http://www.google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.25.36...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.google.com (172.217.25.36) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

This way you can find which path leads to a 200 response from the Mediawiki server.

Answer (score 0):

`Special:Blank` should be a relatively cheap page to test.